# Composer AWS invalid version string ^5.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php

I'm loading AWS API via composer and getting following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
Could not load package aws/aws-sdk-php in http://packagist.org: [Unexpected
ValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^5.3: Invalid version st
ring "^5.3"

[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint ^5.3: Invalid version string "^5.3"
```

Configuration:

```
{
    "name": "RepositoryName",
    "homepage": "http://homepage.elasticbeanstalk.com",
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist",
        "format": "zip",
        "skip-dev": false,
        "absolute-directory": "/var/www/html/web/dist"
    },
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "http://packagist.org" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "abeautifulsite/jquery-minicolors": "2.1.6",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.6.*"
    },
    "require-dependencies": true
}
```

As you can see I am requesting `2.6.*` version, not `^5.3`. Any ideas how to fix that? Running locally and on AWS same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Composer parsing error due to a wrong or unsupported syntax.

The old version of Composer can't handle that `^` operator i think.

Try a `composer self-update` first.

---

- Are you using the latest Elastic Beanstalk stack? The latest stack should ship a more recent version of Composer that supports the new syntax features.
- You can avoid this issue by deploying to production with dependencies pre-installed. That means to "build" your app locally and package it for distribution (that includes all dependencies), then upload/install/configure.
- You could also add a beanstalk configuration file with the goal to run a `composer self-update`.

`.ebextensions\composer.config`

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

Referencing the Symfony 2 AWS Deployment Guide here, because it contains an example for that file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html

And ebextensions guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

---

> I'm using localhost and locally installed Composer. Done `composer self-update`, too

How to install **aws-sdk-php** with Composer?

If you just want to fetch the aws-sdk package to work with it locally, 
you might use the following composer.json file as an example:

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my/project-using-aws-package",
    "require": {
        "abeautifulsite/jquery-minicolors": "2.1.6",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.6.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Run: `composer install -vvv --profile --prefer-dist -o`.

This will install v2.6.16 of aws-sdk-php package. Please note that this is not the latest version, but i think you defined `2.6.*` intentionally. If not consider raising the version.

Comment: I'm using localhost and locally installed Composer. Done `composer self-update`, too

Comment: Hmm, so the question is not about deploying to AWS, but fetching the aws-sdk-php package to work with it locally? Ok, got the question totally wrong. I've updated my answer and included an composer.json file fetching the packages.

Comment: @Justinas I had the same problem and after `composer self-update` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, but I also received the outdate warning:

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.

So, I ran `php composer.phar self-update`
Then `php composer.phar update`

And it worked for me :)